# Adding Int32 to List<byte> using AddRange throwing exception despite being successful

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating an application that will take an image in a certain format from one of a video game's files and convert it to a DDS. This requires me to build the DDS in a buffer and then write it out to a DDS file. This buffer is of type `List<byte>`.

I first write the magic number, which is just the text "DDS ", with this code:

```
ddsFile.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("DDS "));
```

I then need to write the header size, which is always 0x7C000000 (124), and this is where I've hit a wall. I used this code to write it to the buffer:

```
ddsFile.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0x0000007C));
```

This made sense to me because `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()`says itself that it returns a `byte[]`, and it **does** accept an `int` as a parameter, no problem. And additionally, this was what I saw recommended when looking for a method for adding multi-byte values to a byte list. But for whatever reason, when the program tries to execute that line, this exception is thrown:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

But what's even more strange to the point of being ridiculous is that, upon seeing what *did* make it into the buffer, I see that the `int` actually [**was** being written to the buffer, but the exception was still occurring for who knows what reason.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eFuH.png)

Bizarrely, even writing a single byte to the list after writing the magic number e.g. `ddsFile.Add((byte)0x00));` results in the same thing.

Any help in figuring out why this exception occurs and/or a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use a `MemoryStream` and a `BinaryWriter`? Your life would be quite a bit easier - they do all the conversion work for you.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate with the code provided, adding the range with all examples compiles and runs fine. Where are you using your `ddsFile` object?

Comment: You need to show us how you declare `ddsFile`.

Comment: I would guess you run in Release mode and the line numbers are messed up due to optimization. Post the full code!

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] so we could reproduce the issue at our end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer to the question but a suggestion to do it differently.

Instead of using a `List<byte>` and manually doing all the conversions (while certainly possible, it's cumbersome), use a stream and a `BinaryWriter` - the stream can be a memory stream if you want to buffer the image in memory or a file stream if you want to write it to disk right away.

Using a `BinaryWriter` against the stream makes the conversions a lot simpler (and you can still manually convert parts of the data easily, if you need to do so).

Here's a short example:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var bw = new BinaryWriter(ms, Encoding.ASCII);

bw.Write("DDS ");
bw.Write(124); // writes 4 bytes
bw.Write((byte) 124); // writes 1 byte
...
```

Use whichever overload of `Write()` you need to output the right bytes. (This short example omits cleaning up things but if you use a file stream, you'll need to make sure that you properly close it.)

Comment: I think the fact I was using a byte[] to read the original (not DDS) file was what swayed me towards using a List<byte> rather than a MemoryStream, which I'd actually forgotten about until now :p  And really, trying to make the use of the List<byte> work would not have been worth it, so I'd definitely say this is **my** answer, even if it's not necessarily **the** answer.

Comment: @DisplayName I'm glad it was useful.

Comment: @xxbcc a quick update: to put it simply the MemoryStream produced the same problem, but I ended up finding out it and likely the List<byte>, too were being **optimised away by the compiler.** Unchecking **Optimise Code** in the project config fixed everything, so even my original List<byte> method might have worked now, though I've already long written that out and using a MemoryStream is definitely more intuitive.

Comment: @DisplayName You should probably post a new question about that with exact code because that sounds like an unrelated problem that needs looking into. I've never seen MemoryStream behave that way and having to change optimization settings to fix something is a sure sign of a bug somewhere (probably elsewhere). Do you have any `unsafe` code in your project?